# Rails and ActiveModelSerializer: Merging two collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I have two models **ExpenseLog** and **IncomeLog** with one serializer each (using active_model_serializers gem).

I have a controller with a method that should return all the logs (both expensesLogs and incomesLogs) of the last 30 days.
I have to merge both collections, and use the serializer for each item (if it is an ExpenseLog, using ExpenseLogSerializer, and if it is an IncomeLog, using an IncomeLogSerializer).

First, I have two questions:
1) Is there any way to first merging both collections and then serialize them?
2) If not, how can I do to serialize the collection without using the "render json: collection" way? Because I need to store the json result at a variable for merging with the another collection.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) the answer is yes, just merge the two collections into an array and everything should work as expected.

For 2) you can do

```
hash = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(collection).serializable_hash
json = hash.to_json
```